# What is Kernel Mode Setting?

Tags: kms, plymouth

What happens when KMS fails?

Comment: You might want to add some more information to the question (and streamline the subject and question itself). Now you have 2 distinct questions and neither provide information on what you really want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mode setting is basically setting up the screen resolution and the depth mode for the graphics card.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode-setting#LocationBlockquote):

> Mode-setting can be done in kernel space or in user space. Doing mode-setting in kernel-space is more flexible. Doing kernel-based mode-setting allows displaying an error in the case of a fatal error in the kernel, even when using a user-space display server. User-space mode-setting would have needed superuser privileges for direct hardware access. So kernel-based mode-setting increases security because the user-space graphics server does not need superuser privileges.

From [Ubuntu Wiki on Kernel Mode Setting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/KernelModeSetting):

> Kernel mode-setting (KMS) shifts responsibility for selecting and setting up the graphics mode from X.org to the kernel. When X.org is started, it then detects and uses the mode without any further mode changes. This promises to make booting faster, more graphical, and less flickery.

If KMS were to fail, I would think that X would do its own modesetting; instead of having the kernel do it. But that might require you to first disable KMS. More information specifically for different graphics gards can be found on the Ubuntu Wiki article I linked to eariler.